# A terse introduction to Qt?

Tags: qt, reference

Is there a terse introduction to GUI programming with Qt, meant for programmers with a decade's worth of experience (but who don't have any exposure to Qt). I am looking for something that gets one started quickly, and covers all the advanced stuff (including best-practices and patterns). Was looking for something like this book - [Advanced Qt Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635906) - which alas, isn't out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with [Qt Architecture](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt-basic-concepts.html), [Graphics](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt-graphics.html) if you need it, [IO and Networking](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt-network.html), [Model/View](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/model-view-programming.html) (learn and love it),  [Various other APIs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/technology-apis.html), and finally [How To's and Best Practices](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/best-practices.html).  The [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/index.html) is one of the major strengths of the toolkit.  In many cases you won't need other resources.  They even give a quick overview of tips for learning [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/how-to-learn-qt.html).

Note: I'm linking you to the next release documentation since I think it looks better, the current release is [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/index.html).  When reading things over, just look for the comment on when the feature was introduced to make sure it will be available for the release you are using.

Comment: Thanks! I knew about the good (and extensive) documentation, but needed a guide through it. Also, 4.7 is what I am looking at to get started with. I am especially interested in the Qt Quick and QML parts.

Answer (score 0):

[Programming with Qt, Second Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000646/)

Comment: Looks like that's a beginner's book. What I am interested in is something like the O'Reilly 'in a Nutshell' books. In fact, I think, that asking for a book like that would be too much, but is there something online?